# how do get leptonica image library working on mac OS X

Tags: macos, image-processing, ports

Has anyone had any success with the leptonica image libary on mac os x?
I have installed using mac ports but I can't seem to get the libpng and other image libraries to work.

For example, I get the following kind of error, which I assume is linked to libpng

% ./lineremoval dave-orig.png

Error in pixReadStreamPng: function not present

Error in pixReadStream: png: no pix returned

Error in pixRead: pix not read

Error in lineremoval: pix not made

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue. I solved it by  rebuilding leptonica after putting this

```
#ifdef HAVE_LIBZ
#include "zlib.h"
#endif
```

in line 111 of pngio.c.

You can find the details and also a patch file here:
http://code.google.com/p/leptonica/issues/detail?id=56